# From system of coupled ODEs to separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one go from

\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=y\\
\dot{y}&=-x^3
\end{align}

to the following ODE?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x^3}{y}$$

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} \Rightarrow -x^3 = \frac{dy}{dx} y$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that:

$$\dot{x} = y \Rightarrow dx = ydt,$$

and

$$\dot{y} = -x^3 \Rightarrow dy = -x^3 dt.$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x^3dt}{ydt} = -\frac{x^3}{y}$$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\dot{y}=-x^3$. Divide this by $\dot{x}=y$ and we get $\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}=\frac{-x^3}{y}$. But $\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$ is just $\frac{dy}{dx}$ so we're done.